# Modify data in an Access database without giving users permissions over the folder?

Tags: database, ms-access, networking, server, folder-permissions

I have an Access database on a server split in back-end and front-end files (.mdb), so I give users the front-end file and the back-end file is kept in a server. I want users to access the DB and be able of edit and add records. However, I don't want them to access my server for security reasons, let's say a user deleting all files from the server or even worse. So I was thinking in give them reading-only permissions but in such case they won't be able of accessing the database from their computers.

How could I lock the access for the DB folder on the server without preventing the use of the front-end for accessing and modifying data?

Comment: you have to give the users read/write use of that folder. So  you could restrict their rights to JUST that folder, but you have to give users rights to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

That's a hard thing to do. Accessing an Access file requires write permission on the underlying folder, to create/edit/delete the lock file.

Solutions depend on your exact configuration, but this one worked for me:

- Leave the db in a location the user doesn't have access to.
- Create a shared directory the user has read and write access to.
- Create a symlink to the Access file in the shared directory.
- Create a script that deletes all files from the directory
  periodically, and  then recreates the symlink.

Depending on your exact configuration, either access to the symlink is enough to modify the database, or the user actually needs write access on the database.